# Need to Edit command to Delete files in S3 bucket older than 90 days using PowerShell(90days instead of specifying date)

Tags: powershell

Need to Edit command to Delete files in S3 bucket older than 90 days using PowerShell(90days instead of specifying date)

```
$bucketname = "bucketname"
$key = aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket $bucketname --output json --query 'Versions[?LastModified<=`2022-08-26`].{VID:VersionId, Obj:Key}'  | ConvertFrom-Json
Write-host "Removing desired Objects From: $bucketname" -foregroundcolor red
Foreach ($output in $key)
    {
       $delete =  aws s3api delete-object --bucket $bucketname --key ($output).Obj --version-id  ($output).VID --output text
       $output.Obj 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have S3 to test the code but it should fit your needs.

```
$bucketname = "aws-a0189-use1-00-d-s3b-ia-test"
$date = (Get-Date).adddays(-90).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") # 90 days ago
$query = 'Versions[?LastModified<=`' + $date + '`].{VID:VersionId, Obj:Key}'
$key = aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket $bucketname --output json --query $query  | ConvertFrom-Json
Write-host "Removing desired Objects From: $bucketname" -foregroundcolor red
Foreach ($output in $key)
    {
       $delete =  aws s3api delete-object --bucket $bucketname --key ($output).Obj --version-id  ($output).VID --output text
       $output.Obj 
    }
```

in my code I added line two and three. The line two ("$date...") gets the date in the required format a few days back - in this example 90 days.
The line three defines the query and inserts the date in the query.

the line four was changed a bit to include the $query variable

Comment: this code is working fine but it is deleting non-current version too we don't want to delete that...but that was great

Comment: If your question is answered, mark it as answered
`The person who asked can mark one answer as "accepted".
Accepting doesn't mean it's the best answer, it just means that it worked for the person who asked.`
Source: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: the below one is working fine

Answer (score 0):

$bucketname = "bucket name"
$date = (Get-Date).adddays(-2).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") # 2 days ago
$query = 'Versions[?LastModified<=`' + $date + '`].{VID:VersionId, Obj:Key}'
$key = aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket $bucketname --output json --query $query  | ConvertFrom-Json
Write-host "Removing desired Objects From: $bucketname" -foregroundcolor red
Foreach ($output in $key)
{
$delete =  aws s3api delete-object --bucket $bucketname --key ($output).Obj --output text
$output.Obj
}

Comment: please format properly the source code and add some explanation